# Is the text that __func__ expands to standardized?

Tags: c, macros, c99

The existence of a macro named `__func__` is part of C99 and its intent is clear but is the exact text that it expands to within a given function standardized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The macro is defined to expand to the name of the function.

*C11, §6.4.2.2*

> The  identiﬁer _ *func* _ shall  be  implicitly  declared  by  the
> translator  as  if immediately following the opening brace of each
> function deﬁnition, the declaration
>
> static const char _ *func* _[] = "function-name";
>
> appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing
> function.

The standard describes it as equivalent to having a *string literal* with the exact function name. So I don't think there is any other interpretation of that.